# A loop with random numbers inside that come from a separate method and are within an int method

Tags: c#, loops

I am producing a C# version of the Dice game 'Going to Boston' which has three dice and after every role one dice is removed. I want to have this system with a best of 5 loop so that when one of the players reaches five rounds they will win.

This is the random number generator i am using:

```
public static int diceroll0()
{
    Random DiceRoll0 = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    int throw1 = DiceRoll0.Next(1, 18);
    int throw2 = DiceRoll0.Next(1, 12);
    int throw3 = DiceRoll0.Next(1, 6);

    int total0 = (throw1 + throw2 + throw3);
    return total0;
}

public static int diceroll1()
{
    Random DiceRoll1 = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    int throw4 = DiceRoll1.Next(1, 18);
    int throw5 = DiceRoll1.Next(1, 12);
    int throw6 = DiceRoll1.Next(1, 6);

    int total1 = (throw4 + throw5 + throw6);
    return total1;
}

public static int diceroll2()
{   
    Random DiceRoll2 = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    int throw7 = DiceRoll2.Next(1, 18);
    int throw8 = DiceRoll2.Next(1, 12);
    int throw9 = DiceRoll2.Next(1, 6);
    int total2 = (throw7 + throw8 + throw9);
    return total2;
}

public static int diceroll3()
{       
    Random DiceRoll3 = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    int throw10 = DiceRoll3.Next(1, 18);
    int throw11 = DiceRoll3.Next(1, 12);
    int throw12 = DiceRoll3.Next(1, 6);
    int total3 = (throw10 + throw11 + throw12);
    return total3;
}


    int user1points = 0;
    int user2points = 0;

    die rolling = new die();
    int roll0Score = die.diceroll0();
    int roll1Score = die.diceroll1();
    int roll2Score = die.diceroll2();
    int roll3Score = die.diceroll3();
```

Can I loop the system below in any way so that it can be used in a best of 5 format?

```
    //Round 1
    Console.WriteLine("Round 1 rolls:");

    Console.WriteLine(roll0Score);
    Console.WriteLine(roll1Score);

    //Statement to figure which player wins the round
    if (roll0Score > roll1Score)
    {
        user1points++;
    }
    else
    {
        user2points++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Round 1 scores:");

    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has scored " + user1points);
    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has scored " + user2points);
    Console.ReadKey();

    //Round 2

    Console.WriteLine("Round 2 rolls:");

    Console.WriteLine(roll2Score);
    Console.WriteLine(roll3Score);

    if (roll2Score > roll3Score)
    {
        user1points++;
    }
    else
    {
        user2points++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Round 2 scores:");

    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 has scored " + user1points);
    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 has scored " + user2points);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

[This is the full code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dydZ1U)

Comment: What's the significance of `DiceRoll2.Next(1, 18);` - an 18-sided dice?

Comment: (On another note, `diceroll0()`, `diceroll1()` etc. are all exactly equivalent - why do they need to be separate functions?)

Comment: As Dylan is pointing out `Random.Next(1,18)` does not come close to approximating the roll of 3 6-sided dice. For starters, their total must be a minimum of 3. For second, the chances of getting 3 or 18 are significantly lower than the chances of getting 9 or 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. This code is very wrong - firstly, it doesn't follow the rules of the game (it adds up all dice, rather than taking the highest from each roll), and secondly, there is no need to repeat it in this way. I've made a super-simple solution with three classes:

- Die - represents a single die.
- DicePlayer - represents a player and the current score
- DiceGame - represents the entire game.

For simplicity, this solution prints out the game to the console. Example output:

```
Player Bill
Turn 1: rolling 5 4 4 , keeping 5
Turn 2: rolling 1 6 , keeping 6
Turn 3: rolling 6 , keeping 6
Score for round 17

Player Sam
Turn 1: rolling 5 3 1 , keeping 5
Turn 2: rolling 3 5 , keeping 5
Turn 3: rolling 5 , keeping 5
Score for round 15

Player Bill
Turn 1: rolling 6 4 2 , keeping 6
Turn 2: rolling 6 5 , keeping 6
Turn 3: rolling 1 , keeping 1
Score for round 13

Player Sam
Turn 1: rolling 6 1 4 , keeping 6
Turn 2: rolling 2 5 , keeping 5
Turn 3: rolling 5 , keeping 5
Score for round 16

Sam wins - Bill has 30 and Sam has 31
```

The full code here:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var diceGame = new DiceGame(2, new DicePlayer("Bill"), new DicePlayer("Sam"));
    diceGame.PlayGame();
    Console.ReadKey();
}

internal class DiceGame
{
    private readonly int rounds;
    private readonly DicePlayer player1;
    private readonly DicePlayer player2;

    public DiceGame(int rounds, DicePlayer player1, DicePlayer player2)
    {
        this.rounds = rounds;
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
    }

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        var die = new Die();
        for (var i = 0; i < rounds; i++)
        {
            player1.TakeTurn(die);
            player2.TakeTurn(die);
        }

        if (player1.CurrentScore == player2.CurrentScore)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Game is drawn - {player1.Name} has {player1.CurrentScore} and {player2.Name} has {player2.CurrentScore}");
        }
        else if (player1.CurrentScore > player2.CurrentScore)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{player1.Name} wins - {player1.Name} has {player1.CurrentScore} and {player2.Name} has {player2.CurrentScore}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{player2.Name} wins - {player1.Name} has {player1.CurrentScore} and {player2.Name} has {player2.CurrentScore}");
        }
    }
}

internal class DicePlayer
{
    public DicePlayer(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public int CurrentScore { get; private set; }

    public void TakeTurn(Die die)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Player {Name}");
        //In this game, only the highest dice is put aside each time.
        var roundScore = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"Turn {i + 1}: rolling ");
            var max = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3 - i; j++)
            {
                var roll = die.NextRoll();
                Console.Write($"{roll} ");
                if (roll > max)
                {
                    max = roll;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($", keeping {max}");
            roundScore += max;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Score for round {roundScore}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        CurrentScore += roundScore;
    }
}

internal class Die
{
    private readonly Random rng;

    public Die()
    {
        rng = new Random();
    }

    public int NextRoll()
    {
        return rng.Next(1, 7);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would the user set their own names and add more rounds?

Comment: Console.ReadLine() lets you enter some text, that could be used to set a player name.

Comment: What if wanted to do the score based on who had the highest score in the round